# How to make a watermark like this?

Tags: gimp, paint.net

[image: Example of watermark]

If possible I want to make it in paint.net/gimp because I don't have access to PS.
I have tried a few programs for massive watemarking but none of them had the option for the text to look like that.

Comment: Hello Radoslav and welcome to GD. Please include what you've tried and why it didn't work with screenshots. Please edit your post with what your desired results are, what resources you referenced and why those didn't work. See [this meta post](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/699/request-new-close-reason-what-have-you-tried) for discussion and see [this post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried a few programs for massive watemarking but none of them had the option for the text to look like that.

That is why you are thinking of that as a text. It is not a text, it is an image containing a text.

On Gimp:

1) Type a text on a new document. Use a bold typeface and a big size so the effect is more visible. Use a middle gray color.

2) Apply the emboss effect. Filters → Distorts → Emboss.

3) You now need to cut the gray section. "Select by color" and touch the remaining gray on the center of the letters. Delete that. You now have the white border and the black border.

4) Remove the background layer. Save as PNG with transparency.

5) Use that image as a watermark in the massive watermark program you already used.

Comment: What document do you mean? Like a word one? Also I will use transparent one.

Comment: I will edit that part... but were we not refering to GIMP? I also will ad a more specific explanation on the exact look.

Comment: Oh then sorry for my misunderstanding. It's me who's wrong then.

Comment: I'll post a screenshoot. :0)

Comment: I edited for a more detailed answer. No screenshot for the moment Xo)